# Why doesn't Microsoft.NETCore.App support netstandard1.6?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm trying to get started with .NET Core and I'm really having some headaches to understand all this new naming scheme.

Looking at the wiki `netcoreapp1.0` targets the .NET Standard Library 1.6, however when I try to add the `netstandard1.6` instead of `netcoreapp1.0` I get a package restore failed because Microsoft.NetCore.App does not support `netstandard1.6`.

Is it because is delcared like this?

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
```

Also, what does type "platform" means?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest released .Net Core SDK (preview 2)?

Answer (score 10):

What you use and reference depends on whether you are building an application, or a shared library:

- If you are building an **application** (console, UWP, ASP.NET Core web app), you'll target `netcoreapp1.0` and depend on `Microsoft.NetCore.App`. `type: platform` tells NuGet that you are referencing a platform, which doesn't get installed as a package. `netcoreapp1.0` imports `netstandard1.6`, which means it can use libraries that also target `netstandard1.6` or below.
- If you are building a **library** (to be consumed by another library or application), you'll target `netstandard1.X` and either depend on `NETStandard.Library` or directly reference the NuGet packages you need.

Comment: I've seen on the wiki that netcoreapp1.0 is covers netstandard1.6 and net463 also does that, but the net framework 4.6.3 has not been released right?

Comment: @Paleta According to [this document](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms), `net463` will map to `netstandard1.6`. You're right, it hasn't been released yet.

Comment: @NateBarbettini Can you clarify in your answer that `Microsoft.NETCore.App` NuGet requires the tfm `netcoreapp`. The `NETStandard.Library` NuGet requires the tfm `netstandard`. Therefore, a `netcoreapp` (which behind the scenes imports `netstandard`) can use both NuGets, while a `netstandard` library can only refer `NETStandard.Library`.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not quite sure what you mean. My answer already states that `netcoreapp` and `netstandard` are targeted (respectively). Can you elaborate on what you mean by "use both NuGets"?

Comment: netcoreapp1.0 Imports netstandard1.6 which again Imports netatandard1.5 which again Imports netstndard1.4 etc. As a consequences a netcoreapp1.0 can use a netstandard1.5 library but not the others way around. The package `Microsoft.NetCore.App` requires netcoreapp1.0. that is the reason why netstandard1.6 cannot be set above for the project.