# Why do VS 2015 .Net Core apps specify the NetStandardLibrary and not the Core 1.0 library?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, project.json

Visual Studio 2015 (with the support for .NET Core added on) gives you the option of creating a .NET Core library, or a .NET Core console app. If you do so, and look at the project's .json file, it looks like it's "limiting" you to the api defined by NetStandardLibrary 1.6:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

My understanding is that .net core 1.0 actually has a larger api than NetStandardCore, so why is VS 2015 defaulting your app to only accessing the api's specified in the NetStandardLibrary 1.6?

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that .net core 1.0 actually has a larger api than NetStandardCore

That isn't correct. The .NET Standard Library defines a particular API surface area depending on the version.

The **higher** the version number, the more APIs you have access to. The **lower** the version number, the more compatible your code is with other platforms (like older versions of .NET, or mobile devices). `netstandard1.6` is the highest and largest API right now.

.NET Core 1.0 or `netcoreapp1.0` targets `netstandard1.6`. In other words, they have the same APIs available. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38165509/3191599) explains which moniker you should use:

- `netstandard1.X` for class libraries
- `netcoreapp1.0` for applications