# How to test a controller in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application (`NetCoreApp1.1`) Web API project and I would like to test a controller of that project. I added a .NET Core class library (targeting `NetStandard1.6`).

Now the problem I have is that according to [Why doesn't Microsoft.NETCore.App support netstandard1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165411/why-doesnt-microsoft-netcore-app-support-netstandard1-6) I can't reference the Web API project from that class library.

My question is then, does this mean that unless the controllers are placed somewhere else I won't be able to test them anymore? Maybe there is a way to do so but I haven't been able to achieve it in VS 2017 RC.

Comment: Why don't you create an xunittest project to run your tests?

Comment: Would that allow referencing a NetCoreApp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test projects should be console applications, not class libraries. A console application references `Microsoft.NETCore.App` and shouldn't have any problems referencing your Web API project.

A simple example of the `project.json` for a working test project is:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "MyApiProject": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dotnet"
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
}
```

If you're using `.csproj` in VS 2017, it'll look different, but the principle should be the same. The test project can reference the API project locally, and uses a test runner like Xunit to run tests.

Comment: That worked and made sense. Thanks! My next challenge is to get NUnit running from VS 2017 RC