# Why does Visual Studio 2017 target netcoreapp when creating a new Class Library project

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

From [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165411/why-doesnt-microsoft-netcore-app-support-netstandard1-6):

"If you are building a library (to be consumed by another library or application), you'll target netstandard1.X"

"If you are building an application (console, UWP, ASP.NET Core web app), you'll target netcoreapp1.0"

However when I create new .net core class library project in Visual Studio 2017 I see this:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
```

Why does a class library target netcoreapp?

Answer (score 1):

In the New Project wizard you should select .NET Standard from the left tree.

[image: netstandard project template]

After creating project I get this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I have no idea why there is also a similar project in .NET Core section and its purpose but for most cases .NET Standard is right choice for Class Library projects.